# pyspark sort starting from different values on repeated run

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a spark dataframe match_historic_product_df.  It has an id field in it match_id.  I'm trying to sort the distinct values of match_id and number them using the code below.  What I am noticing is that if I run the code multiple times it will start in a different spot ordering the match_id, when I run show() to check the code output.  Can someone please explain why it keeps sorting match_id from a different starting value, and how can I set it to always start from the beginning?  Is this just a show() issue because it's sampling 20 records, does the code work correctly when run without show() and sorts the entire dataset?

code:

```
ordered_hist_match=match_historic_product_df[['match_id']].distinct().sort('match_id',ascending=True)

ordered_hist_match= ordered_hist_match.withColumn("new_column",lit("ABC"))

w = Window().partitionBy('new_column').orderBy(lit('A'))
ordered_hist_match = ordered_hist_match.withColumn("row_num", row_number().over(w)).drop("new_column")

ordered_hist_match.show()
```

Example output:

```
first run

match_id row_num
0        1
1        2
2        3

2nd run


match_id row_num
3351     1
3352     2
3353     3
```

Answer (score 0):

why are you ordering by `lit('A')`? Use `match_id` instead

```
w = Window().partitionBy('new_column').orderBy('match_id')
```